# HDD old deleted data still visible in recovery software

Tags: data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, file-recovery, secure-erase, recovery

Hi How can i completely wipe **old deleted data** from hard disk i am trying with **ccleaner** and cleaning the /w **Free Space (35 Pass)** after cleaning the free space i scanned my laptop with **easeus data recovery** software after full scanning recovery software is detecting only 4 files then i used **revo uninstaller** and **PrivaZer** to remove the traces and remove the files names from **$MFT** after the competition of process i restarted my laptop and again scanned the laptop with **easeus and recuva** now both softwares detecting all **deleted files** from this window and from previous window

**here is screenshot**

[image]

how can i permanently wipe this data from hard disk

**System :**

`HP G72250us`
`220 gb HDD`
`Windows 8.1`

Comment: Encrypt the data with BitLocker and/or Veracrypt and then delete the partitions on the drive.  The data at that point cannot be recover by anyone

Comment: @Ramhound you mean to say first i encrypt whole disk with Veracrypt then remove the partitions using bootable usb? and then reinstall new window by creating new partitions? and what about MFT? please provide me any tutorial link so i can follow the steps thanks

Comment: What is MFT in the context your using it?  Within Windows or Linux you would encrypt the drive, then after the encryption process was completed, you would delete the partitions on the drive.  There isn’t a link to follow since 2 steps.  If you don’t know how to encrypt a drive with BitLocker or Veracrypt you would have to research that yourself